# Oversampling problems in prediction

Tags: python, random-forest, oversampling

I have a dataset that contains 284315 samples of class 0 and 492 of class 1. I know, that's huge.
I heard about oversampling methods, so I did the following using the RandomOverSampler library:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
X_resampled, y_resampled = ros.fit_sample(X, y)
```

I trained a Random Forest classifier over this resampled data, and the confusion matrix looks like this:

```
array([[92005,  1833],
       [    8,   141]], dtype=int64)
```

So yeah, It got a 10-folds cv score of 0.9945, but the model is obviously classifying everything that it could to class 0. 
I know that this is a difficult problem because of the ratio, but is there anything I could do to get a more accurate performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling will not solve a non-problem: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading a little bit, I changed the oversampling approach. Now I penalize the bigger class with class_weight="balanced". Also tuning the hyperparameters reduced the false negative to 3!